# How to setup the quota for NIS user

Tags: ubuntu, nis, quota

I have 3 VM's and configured NIS server one VM, user account created for client access also done. NIS client configured remaining two VM's. I am able to login through what I created username in NIS server side.

Now I want to allocate the quota for that nis user. How to allocate quota

Comment: Were you able to get quota setup for your nis user?

Answer (score 0):

File system quotas are setup and viewed using the packages `quota` and `quotatool`. Mounts will need to have the options `usrquota`,`grpquota` added. You'll need to enable quota's on your server using `quotaon(8)`. You can do this via `/etc/init.d/quota` or `service quota start`. You can edit quota with `edquota(8)`. If you encounter any problems, ensure that `rpc.rquotad(8)` is running on your server. It responds to quota requests from the clients.

There is a nice little tutorial here:

http://timstaley.co.uk/posts/setting-up-disk-quotas-with-ubuntu-1204/